# Android Hardware Back Button not triggering 'popstate'

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile

In a mobile SPA app, I have overridden the default back behavior to switch between pages.

```
        // create history states
        history.pushState(-1, null); // back state
        history.pushState(0, null); // main state
        history.pushState(1, null); // forward state
        history.go(-1); // start in main state
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
            var state = event.state;
            if (state === -1) {                    
                if (!this.goBack()) {
                    return false;
                }

                // reset state to what it should be
                history.go(-state);
            }
        }, false);
```

Which works great for all mobile devices, except when there is a hardware back button on certain Android Devices (Samsung S5, BlackBerry Key 2 are two that I am testing that it happens to).  The popstate event is never called when the hardware back button is pressed, so the user gets dumped out of the application rather than going back a page.  Is there any known way of intercepting this hardware back button through Javascript?

To be clear, back is working perfectly for allmost all devices, except those which have a hardware back button (not a softbutton or swipe back like in Android 10) which doesn't seem to trigger the history popstate event.

Answer (score 1):

I know two approaches but those rely on thirdparty frameworks:

**1. jQuery mobile**

```
  $(window).on("navigate", function(event, data){
      if(direction == "back") {
          // back
      } elseif(direction == "forward") {
          // forward
      }
  });
```

---

**2. React Native**

It offers a `BackHandler` for this specific purpose:

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
    // this.onMainScreen and this.goBack are just examples, you need to use your own implementation here
    // Typically you would use the navigator here to go to the last state.

    if(!this.onMainScreen()) {
        this.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

---

If it's not a problem for you to use such a framework you better go for it, as they put a lot of effort in crossbrowser support and upcoming changes/additions. I can recommend jQuery mobile myself.

Comment: $('window').on('navigate') is wrapper around popstate (https://api.jquerymobile.com/navigate/) so if popstate isn't triggering an event, navigate isn't going to trigger an event.  React Native is a native platform, and I am working in a standard mobile web page.

Comment: Thank you Kris for that additional information! To be honest I don't think it's possible then. Looked promising. But I guess the close-app functionality of the OS can't be prevented by javascript in a browser. If you find anything else that works I'd appreciate a further notice!